# How can I prevent gdb from a segfault on print or what can I learn from it?

Tags: fortran, gdb

I am getting this weird error again and again

Declaration of a variable `iw` is as follows:

```
       integer iw         (line 28)
```

Another thing I must mention is that I have a print statement just a few lines above that executes properly:

```
      write(*,*) ' IW=', iw     (line 89)
```

But then a few lines later, I get:

```
(gdb) p iw
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So the question as stated in the title consists of two parts: (a) How can I prevent gdb from a segfault on print here and (b) what can I learn from the segfault ?

Answer (score 3):

When gdb crashes, it is always a bug in gdb.  I'm afraid that when this happens, you have few options.  You don't say what version of gdb you are using, though, so maybe upgrading would help.

Otherwise, the best thing to do is try to come up with a minimal example and file a bug.  An excellent bug report would also include the stack trace from gdb.  You can try something like:

```
$ gdb --args gdb your-program
```

Then in the outer gdb, run the inner gdb; then debug your program; and when the inner gdb crashes, use `bt` to get a stack trace you can file in the gdb bug report.

This only really works well if you have debug symbols for gdb.  If you want to try to fix gdb, you'd be best off building your own.

Comment: I circumvented this problem by using the standard gdb instead of Archer branch. I learned that at the root of my problem was in some offending lines in my source using an array. Commenting those lines eliminated my  problem.